# How does Yahoo's new automatic loading work?

Tags: javascript, performance, load, yahoo

In the new Yahoo mail inbox, when u click the message it is displayed in a tab automatically (I guess with out server interaction). Does that mean Yahoo loads all the data first and then use them with java script when requested or not...anyho i don't have any idea and I would like if some one explain to me how it works since am planning to do the same with my application. I am sure this will boost application performance and i am eager to know.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen it but what you're describing sounds like dynamic AJAX loading. Basically, only load information when it is requested by the user. This will reduce network load and initial loading times. Most JS libraries have some form of AJAX helper. You can read more on AJAX [here](http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/ajax-new-approach-web-applications) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax).

Comment: I am sure there is a lot of Ajax involved but that is a headach by itself. I mean if u load the whole data at once then it must be very slow when its called first. But it aint slow at first and its amazing after that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to know. It's not magic. They use AJAX. They could be loading a lot of stuff in the background, or loading it all at once, or loading it on click. It could be that their server has a very fast response time. You just have to experiment with it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Yahoo did something similar to what Hotmail describes [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2010/05/18/re-inventing-windows-live-hotmail-the-next-generation-of-personal-email.aspx)

Basically they decide depending on several aspect what+when to preload...

Comment: tnx but we are talking different things what i am trying to learn is how yahoo could make the whole thing so fast. Anyho I have added an image in the question to help u see. Like i commented in the answer below i don't think its all ajax I mean Ajax is about loading ur data at first and reusing it with out server request.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure it does have some server interaction. It definitely is using some sort of AJAX  to fetch data from the server and show it to you. There are tons of tutorials about using AJAX which you can refer. You can probably start with http://w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: if there are tons, you should provide some appropriate links or put this as comment. not an answer